# Get All Relationship Types Defined in Current Database

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

Is there any efficient way to get all relationship types currently defined?

I know this works:

```
match ()-[r]-() RETURN DISTINCT TYPE(r)
```

But I guess this will consume significant time if the number of relationships is huge and  there is no inherent indexing under the hood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CALL db.relationshipTypes()
```

To learn more about what mysteries a graph holds see
[How to get a high level inventory of objects in your graph](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-to-get-a-high-level-inventory-of-objects-in-your-graph/)

---

At https://neo4j.com/download/ you can down load Neo4j desktop which will install a local copy of Neo4j server. Here is the online [guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-desktop/).

In there is a list of sample queries to help you learn about a database.

[image]